# get Layers list only in SVF2 models?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have the same nwd model translated two times in Forge.
One in classic SVF, one in SVF2.

If I test with the SVF2 model, everything working fine when I use:

' var root = viewer.impl.getLayersRoot();

The variable root contains a list of all layers

When I test with SVF model the same code:

'  var root = viewer.impl.getLayersRoot();

The variable Root now it's empty.

Why?

There is an official API  to get the list of all layers in SVF  models?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The layers are typically accessed via `viewer.model.getData().layersRoot`. This is working for SVF as well.

Comment: Maybe I missing something.  If I type in my browser console viewer.model.getData().layersRoot, the result from it is "undefined".  On both the SVF and SVF2 models.
For now I get list of layers only in SVF2 using viewer.impl.getLayersRoot();
I am using the latest viewer available 7.80

Comment: That's strange. In that case I'd suggest that you share your design with us (confidentially) via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` if possible so that we can debug it on our end.